# Is it possible for me to identify what services are using an AWS Lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lambda

I'm trying to clean up some Lambda functions in our account. When I click on the Monitor tab for each function, everything is coming up with "No data available". I know at least one of those functions are associated with a CloudFront distribution, and I was able to pull up that function's logs via CloudFront. But I don't know where to look for any information or logs for the other functions.

Basically, I want to verify whether or not the other functions are being used/invoked at all so that I know I'm not disrupting anything if I delete them.

Comment: Cloudwatch Logs and CloudTrail would be the two places to look for this information

Comment: Was able to track it down, thank you! Unclear why the data was showing within CloudWatch, but not within the CloudWatch tab from the Lambda function page, but at least I was able to find it.